# How to make a gif of a rotating 3D graph?

Tags: graphics3d

I can make a ListAnimation of a rotating Graphics3D object using the following:

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {1, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
  ViewVector -> {5 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t], 10 Sin[t/2]}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True], {t, 0, 4 \[Pi], .1}]]
```

[image]

How do I do the same for this 3D graph?

```
Graph3D[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1

    , 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6
    , 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11,   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12
   , 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 9
 

     }
      ,
      VertexLabels -> "Name",
      VertexSize -> Medium,
      VertexStyle -> {
         1 -> Orange,
         2 -> Orange,
         3 -> Orange,
         4 -> White,
         5 -> White,
         6 -> Purple,
         7 -> White,
         8 -> Purple,
         9 -> White,
         10 -> White,
         11 -> Purple,
         12 -> White

         },
       EdgeStyle ->
        {
         1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> Orange,
         2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> Orange,
         3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 -> Orange
         }
       ]
```

[image]

is there anyway to turn this 3D graph into a graphics3D object?

Comment: `Graph3D` does supports `Graphics3D` options. You can use `ViewVector`.

Answer (score 9):

One option is  [ExportRotatingGIF](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExportRotatingGIF/)

[image]

And the standalone gif `example.gif` created in the same folder as the notebook looks like this:

[image]

code

```
g = Graph3D[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 9}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> Medium, 
   VertexStyle -> {1 -> Orange, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Orange, 4 -> White, 
     5 -> White, 6 -> Purple, 7 -> White, 8 -> Purple, 9 -> White, 
     10 -> White, 11 -> Purple, 12 -> White}, 
   EdgeStyle -> {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> Orange, 
     2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> Orange, 
     3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 -> Orange}];
ResourceFunction["ExportRotatingGIF"]["example.gif", g];
Import[%, "Animation", ImageSize -> Small]
```

I have not tried to see if there are options to change the rotation/angle and so on.

Yes, it has these options

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to export the result to a GIF, the problem is that the resource function `ExportRotatingGIF` has the limitation that the rotation has to be around one of the axes. I have adapted it for rotation around any vector.

First, observe the rotation of the viewpoint. The graph is the cube:

```
vectorForAxis = {.6, .7, 1}; initialPoint = {1, 2, .5};
Graphics3D[{Cube[],
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, vectorForAxis}],(*axis of rotation*)
  (*Point[{2.5,4.5,2.4}]original viewpoint*)
  Table[Point[RotationMatrix[rotn, vectorForAxis] . initialPoint]
   , {rotn, 0, 3 \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/20}]
  }]
```

Then, adapt the `ExportRotatingGIF` for this vector:

```
exportRotatingGIF[fileName_, graphics : Blank[Graphics3D], 
  OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{imgs, dir, fn, frameCount, parallel, tmpdir, axis, v, a, vv, 
   addg3dopts, fps, sec, vwPt, is, ir}, 
  {ir, is, vwPt, fps, sec, parallel, tmpdir, axis, addg3dopts} = 
   OptionValue[{ImageResolution, ImageSize, "InitialViewPoint", 
     "FPS", "Duration", "Parallel", "FramesDirectory", "Axis", 
     "Graphics3DOptions"}];
   frameCount = fps*sec;
   dir = If[tmpdir === Automatic, CreateDirectory[], tmpdir]; 
  If[ ! DirectoryQ[dir], 
   CreateDirectory[dir, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]];
   (*Switch[ToLowerCase[axis], 
  "x", a = {1, 0, 0}; vv = RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}][
  vwPt],
   "y", a = {0, 1, 0}; vv = RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}][
  vwPt],
   "z", a = {0, 0, 1}; vv = RotationTransform[{vwPt, a}][vwPt],
   _, Return[$Failed]]*)a = vectorForAxis;
   If[parallel, ParallelDo, Do][
   fn = FileNameJoin[{dir, StringTemplate["src``.png"][i]}]; 
   Export[fn, 
    Graphics3D[graphics[[1]], 
     ViewPoint -> 
      RotationTransform[(i - 1)*(2.*(Pi/frameCount)), a][
       vwPt], (*ViewVertical -> RotationTransform[(i - 1)*(2.*(Pi/
     frameCount)), a][vv], *)
     Sequence @@ FilterRules[addg3dopts, Options[Graphics3D]], 
     SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     RotationAction -> "Clip", ViewAngle -> Automatic, 
     Lighting -> "Neutral"], ImageSize -> is(*, ImageResolution -> 
    ir*)], {i, frameCount}]; 
  imgs = Table[
    Import[FileNameJoin[{dir, StringTemplate["src``.png"][i]}]], {i, 
     frameCount}]; 
  Export[fileName, imgs, N["DisplayDurations" -> 1/fps], 
   ImageSize -> is(*, ImageResolution -> ir*), 
   "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]]

exportRotatingGIF[fileName_, (g_MeshRegion) | (g_Graph), 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 exportRotatingGIF[fileName, Show[g], opts]
 
Options[exportRotatingGIF] = {"FPS" -> 36, "Duration" -> 18, 
  "Parallel" -> False, "FramesDirectory" -> Automatic, "Axis" -> "z", 
  "InitialViewPoint" -> initialPoint(*{3, 0, 0}*), 
  "Graphics3DOptions" -> {}, ImageSize -> 800, 
  ImageResolution -> Automatic}
```

Then, apply it to your graph:

```
exportRotatingGIF[ yourpath, yourgraph]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Just apply Show:

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Show[g, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}, 
   ViewVector -> {5 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t], 10 Sin[t/2]}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, Lighting -> Automatic], {t, 0, 
   4 \[Pi], .1}]]
```