# ListPointPlot3D to rotating gif

Tags: graphics3d, export

Does anyone have any experience with the resource function ExportRotatingGif?  I have a 3D scatter plot I would like to export as a gif file so that other people in my office can view it easily, but I have yet to be able to do so successfully.

The data is imported from .CSV files and the graph is generated by

```
graph1 = 
 ListPointPlot3D[{data2013237, data201871, data201873B, data201891A}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> {L, a, b},
   PlotLegends -> {2013237, 201871, 201873 B, 201891 A}]
```

The output when I try to run ExportRotatingGif looks like this:
[image] and no file is generated.

All the other solutions I have seen on stack exchange use animate functions, and I haven't been able to make those work with a scatter plot from collected data sets, not a function.

Sorry for the basic question, I haven't used Mathematica for years and I am definitely rusty.

Comment: Similar to [267868](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267868/how-to-make-a-gif-of-a-rotating-3d-graph).

Comment: I looked at that, but it doesn't have any troubleshooting tips for ExportRotatingGif

Comment: post your code plz

Answer (score 1):

You can generate gifs by computing all frames with `Table` or `ParallelTable` and letting Mathemtica combining them into a gif upon using `Export`

Example:

```
gif = Table[
  ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}],
    ViewPoint -> vwpnt], {vwpnt, {Front, Left, Back, Right}}]
Export["gif.gif", gif, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

Yields:

[image]

`"DisplayDurations"` controls the frame time for the gif in seconds. Leaving this option makes gifs with few frames too jittery to look at. To make it easier to control the frames for the viewer, you might also export it as an mp4 file:

```
Export["gif.mp4", gif]
```

For mp4 you might also be able to get away with less frames and control frame times with `FrameRate` upon export, but I didn't test it.
Depending on your data and desired viewpoints you will need to play around with appropriate values for `ViewPoint` or  `ViewVector`.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go!